# Allow insecure connection on nginx

Tags: nginx, https

I have a website running on nginx and with HTTPS enabled. For any http request, I redirect users to https. The problem is that some of our clients can't access the website from their work computer due to their firewall blocking the page.

That is, Google Chrome show `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`.

Is there a way I can redirect to HTTPS (open in HTTPS by default) when possible yet also allow HTTP access. Of course I can disable redirect to HTTPS, but then all pages will open in HTTP by default.

Following are my server blocks

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.abcd.com;
    return 301   https://www.abcd.com$request_uri;
    # Want to open https page when possible
}


server{
    listen        443 ssl;
    server_name   www.abcd.com;

    ssl_certificate      /home/xyz.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/xyz.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "Something Something";

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically what you want to do, is get the client to use https unless they can't. The problem is the server won't know they can't in this instance because the connection is being terminated on the client firewall.

Comment: Are you using a certificate from a trusted authority or is it self-signed?

Comment: @bangal I'm using trusted authority certificates (GoDaddy).

Comment: I don't think, it will be possible what you wish. I would rather suggest to investigate more why the particular client Firewall blocking the site in HTTPS. Can they access it in HTTP? Is there any additional error messages?